# Inserting a variable in a table call

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

I've declared a variable

`DECLARE @DB varchar(99)='Table2017'`

and am trying to use this variable in a join to a database object:

`Join @DB.dbo.Table3 U on A.ID = U.AccountID`

using `'+ @DB +'.dbo.Table3` is incorrect syntax as well as `'@DB'.dbo.Table3` and `'+@DB+'.dbo.Table3`. Any ideas on how I can do this while keeping the @DB reference as varchar?

Comment: Try making the entire statement dynamic, not just the database reference.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use parameter as object name. You need to create your **all** code dynamic and execute it.

for example:

```
declare @sqlt nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @DB varchar(99)='Table2017'

set @sqlt = 'select * from ' + @DB + '.dbo.Table3 U left join U on A.ID = U.AccountID'
exec sp_executesql @sqlt
```

Comment: Why not `sp_executesql` ? Please [read this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/turgays/2013/09/17/exec-vs-sp_executesql/)

Answer (score 1):

Use `sp_executesql` as next demo:-

```
DECLARE 
    @FirstTable varchar(99)='Table1', 
    @SecondTable varchar(99)='Table2',

    @MyQuery nvarchar(200) =
    'SELECT column_name(s)
    FROM ' + @FirstTable + '
    INNER JOIN ' + @SecondTable + 
    ' ON '+ @FirstTable +'.column_name = '+ @SecondTable +'.column_name'

exec sp_executesql @MyQuery
```

Comment: Why not `sp_executesql` ? Please [read this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/turgays/2013/09/17/exec-vs-sp_executesql/)

Comment: Based on my knowledge , the both in this case are the same.

Comment: No , read the page from the link please ."sp_executesql allows for statements to be parameterized"

Comment: Thanks for the article, the answer has been updated.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use dynamic sql as below:

```
declare @query varchar(max)
declare @DB varchar(99)='Table2017'

select @query = ' select * from ' +  @DB + '.dbo.Table3'
exec sp_executesql @query
```

Comment: OP say "trying to use this variable in a join"

Comment: This is the idea and OP can modify for his query, because OP did not provided other table and join details

Comment: By the way what is OP mean?

Comment: @KannanKandasamy OP refers to **O**riginal **P**oster